# Could not find a version that satisfied the requirement tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, pip

Python version= python 3.6
Operating system: Linux horyan1211-desktop 4.9.253-tegra #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Feb 19 08:59:22 PST 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

while using pip install tensorflow

it show:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Help to install tensorflow with coding

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Btensorflow%5D+aarch64

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are installing the right Tensorflow version as per this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#linux), means if you have installed python 3.6 version in your system then you will not be able to install TensorFlow version > 2.6.

Please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) to install tensorflow with the specific version in your system.